# Step into the non-innermost call in an expression with PDB

Tags: python, pdb

Consider a piece of code like this:

```py
breakpoint()
x = foo(bar(baz()))
```

In PDB (or PDB++), the `step` command normally would step into the `baz()` function.

How can I step into the call to `bar()` or `baz()` instead of `baz()`? I don't see anything about this in the PDB or PDB++ documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the list of debugger commands [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

You can either put a breakpoint using `break` or temporary breakpoint using `tbreak` in foo or bar:

```
$ python3 x.py 
> /tmp/0/x.py(14)<module>()
-> x=foo(bar(baz(42)))
(Pdb) break foo
Breakpoint 1 at /tmp/0/x.py:1
(Pdb) continue
> /tmp/0/x.py(2)foo()
-> ret=x+1
```

or run until the `baz` end using `return` and then `step` again:

```
$ python3 x.py 
> /tmp/0/x.py(14)<module>()
-> x=foo(bar(baz(42)))
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> /tmp/0/x.py(9)baz()
-> def baz(x):
(Pdb) return
--Return--
> /tmp/0/x.py(11)baz()->45
-> return ret
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> /tmp/0/x.py(5)bar()
-> def bar(x):
(Pdb) return
--Return--
> /tmp/0/x.py(7)bar()->47
-> return ret
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> /tmp/0/x.py(1)foo()
-> def foo(x):
```